# Recursive lambda in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda

Let's see analyse code for factorial in Haskell using lambda function:

```
y f x = f (y f) x

factorial = y (\t n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * t(n-1))
```

And I cannot understand how does it works. I know that it is connected with lambda calculus but nowadays I am not familiar with that so I have to understand without it or with minimal knowledge.
My doubt is:
What is f in definition of factorial? I mean this f: y **f** x = f (y f) x.

So what is f here?  y (\t n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * t(n-1))

Please explain me that, maybe expand recursion?

Comment: Note the lambda itself is not recursive; it just takes a function which it applies to `n - 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `f`in `factorial` is the `(\t n -> if n == 1 ...)` *lambda*

`y` is a so called [fix-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) and it's used to enable recursive definitions in the lambda-calculus (it applies `f` to it's argument again and again recursively)

to understand how it works you can just do some *evaluation by hand*:

```
factorial 3
= y (\t n -> ...) 3
{ def y and y (\t n -> ...) = factorial by eta-red. }
= (\t n -> ...) factorial 3
{ t = factorial, n = 3 -> else case }
= 3 * factorial 2
= 3 * (y (\t n -> ...) 2)
= 3 * ((\t n -> ...) factorial 2)
= { t = factorial, n = 2 -> else case }
= 3 * (2 * factorial 1)
= 3 * (2 * (y (\t n -> ...) 1))
= 3 * (2 * ((\t n -> ...) factorial 1)))
{ t = factorial n = 1 -> then case }
= 3 * (2 * 1)
= 6
```

Comment: Ok, I have a doubt with that: t(n-1). t is our lambda function. t ( lambda)  gets TWO arguments while we give one argument ( n -1). My guess is that is connected with laziness of Haskell? Can you explain me it in more details? If you suggest, I'll create a new subject,

Comment: no `t` has only one argument and if you look closely we only call it ever with one - the lambda part is the `\ t n -> ...` - see this (unnamed) function takes two arguments: one is `t` and the other is `n` - this is the tricky mind-bending part as this enables us to define recursive with only the `y`-fix point combinator

Comment: It it is caused by the fact that the recursion will be infinitely ( to stop constraint)  expanded and there is no 'place for t argument'.  Am I right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say - the recursion here will stop because you finally hit the `then` branch where you don't use `t` again (the part where `y` brings in the recursive call into the computation) - although I talked about laziness at first it's not really needed here as `if` will evaluate only one branch in most lang. I know (in ML/F#, etc. it will work as is) and I decided it might confuse to much here

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help and patience! :)

Answer (score 1):

`y` is the [fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator), also known as the y-combinator. In

```
factorial = y (\t n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * t(n-1))
```

the lambda `(\t n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * t(n-1))` is bound to `f` in the definition of `y`. You can then do the expansion:

```
(\t n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * t(n-1)) (y (\t n -> if n == 1 then 1 else n * t(n-1)))
```

so inside the lambda, `t` will be bound to the lambda itself, which allows it to call itself recursively.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's easier if you write out the *y* combinator thus, with two eta-expansions:

```
y :: ((a->b) -> a->b) -> a->b
y f x a = f (\q a' -> y f q a') x a
```

So `f` basically gets the recursive call (with `a'` in place of `a`) as its first argument.